# Showing that if A$\subset$E$\subset$B and lebesgue measures of A and B are equal and finite, then E is lebesgue measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working on the following question:

Suppose that A ⊂ E ⊂ B, where A and B are λ-measurable sets of finite measure. Prove that if λ(A) = λ(B), then E is λ-measurable.

I am working with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

I have currently:

If A, B are λ-measurable sets of finite measure then they must also be λ*-measurable sets of finite measure, where λ* denotes the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb R$.

Meaning they must satisfy λ*(S)=λ*(S$\cap$A)+λ*(S$\cap$$A^c$) and λ*(S)=λ*(S$\cap$B)+λ*(S$\cap$$B^c$).

I also must have that: A$\subset$E, so λ*(A)$\le$λ*(E) and E$\subset$B so λ*(E)$\le$λ*(B) as a consequence of outer measure. But I am unsure of how to progress with this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E\setminus A\subseteq B\setminus A,$ and $B\setminus A$ is Lebesgue measurable with measure $0.$ It follows that $E\setminus A$ is also measurable (with measure $0),$ so $E=A\cup (E\setminus A)$ is measurable, being the union of two measurable sets.

Comment: Thank you, I was going in the complete wrong direction! Your help is much appreciated :D

Comment: There are other approaches also. If you've studied inner measure, you could prove that the inner measure of $E$ equals the outer measure of $E.$

Comment: I am actually self studying, using Warwicks course notes and example sheets. I sit in on some Measure Theory seminars but was unable to take the course formally due to clashes. I am going to look up inner measures and see if I can construct the alternate proof also! Thank you for the insight!